# tangent functions

Tags: analysis

let $A,B \subset \Bbb K $
$f:A \rightarrow \Bbb K $
$ g:B \rightarrow \Bbb K $
$ a \in \Bbb K $

We say f is tangent to g if
$ a \in int  (A \cap B)$
and
$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall z \in \Bbb K: [\  |z-a| \lt  \delta, z \in (A\cap B)\ ] \Rightarrow [\  |g(z)-f(z)| \le \epsilon|a-z|\ ] $

Now lets say, that
$f(x) = sin(x)$
$g(x) = 0$
$a=0$

How can I show, that f and g are tangent?

Comment: Your definition of "f is tangent to g" does not seem to involve the function $g$. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan you have right, thank you :)

Comment: What you are now asking for is $|\sin(x)| \leq \epsilon |x|$ for $x$ close to zero. But $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$, so this won't be possible. Perhaps you want to define what $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: ok, thats it. It just was a mistake. A = $ \Bbb K $.
Thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inspection of the definition of "$f$ is tangent to $g$ at $a$" shows it to be the same thing as "the function $h=f-g$ satisfies $h(a)=0=h'(a)$".

This gives a practical way of checking whether tangency holds. Of course, 
$$(\sin x-0)' = \cos x\ne 0 \quad \text{when $x=0$}$$